# Windows 7 is jerky, visually, with three monitors

Tags: windows-7, multiple-monitors, 64-bit, lag, eyefinity

When dragging Windows across all three monitors, it appears that they jerk around, at maybe 10-15FPS. YouTube and Netflix play in very low frame rates, probably skipping frames, and when scrolling in Chrome, it also appears jerky.

I have run Windows Experience Index and installed the latest AMD drivers (I have an R9 290 by the way), it's still laggy/jerky/just not smooth.

However, something strange happens when I enable AMD Eyefinity on the three displays; it's actually smooth! When dragging windows across all three monitors, it remains a nice, constant 60FPS without any visual stutter.

How would I fix this so that it runs silky smooth like this without Eyefinity? (I personally can't stand Eyefinity for anything besides games, so leaving it on is not an option. For example, you can't have more than one thing full screened, and it's on all monitors. So, just no...)

Comment: have you tried connecting a single monitor first to see if that issue appears? Then again with 2 monitors? Does it only happen with 3?

Comment: Two monitors seem less so (jerkiness), and one monitor seems to run everything at 60FPS. When going from one back to two, it seems less jerky than before, but still not as smooth as just the one. It seems to be very smooth with two monitors when dragging on one monitor, but as soon as I drag it to another monitor, it jerks. But remember, it runs totally fine with Eyefinity on all three, so it's not a performance issue. I just noticed, the main display always seems to not lag at all.

Comment: hmm - Are all 3 monitors the same? Are the refresh rates different? Just trying to rule out some simple possible issues - What version of Windows you running? Is Aero on/off?

Comment: Windows 7, all different model monitors, all 60Hz, all Dell. If I change the main display to another, that one runs fine then. Aero is on.

Comment: You are making all video changes through the catalyst control center correct? I know if you use Windows drivers, it will not work properly - If Eyefinity is working, it sounds like by default, Windows are loading video drivers and controlling your monitor rather than AMD's CCC

Comment: Video changes? Like changing which monitor is the main one? That's through Windows. What should I uninstall then in Device Manager? Under Display adapters, only AMD Radeon R9 200 Series shows up.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/38288/discussion-between-mike-diglio-and-trivisionzero).